# Java - Create variables from the elements of an ArrayList like Python?

Tags: java, arraylist

Programming with Java, I have an `ArrayList<Integer>` with values of `[1,2,3]` and I want to create separate integer variables `a`, `b`, and `c` that contain values from the ArrayList in the order that I create them. In Python I would:

```
l = [1,2,3]
a,b,c = l
```

and `a`, `b`, and `c` would have the values `1`, `2`, `3`, respectively. How would you do that in Java?

Comment: Auugh, JB Nizet's and AlexWien's take too much lines... is there some way I can do it with mapping or something?

Comment: No. That's the only way. That's something or very rarely need to do anyway. Most of the time, if you have a list, you're not interested in its first three elements, but on all of them, so you iterate on them. My guess is that you're using an array to store three values that should be attributes of an object instead. But you aren't telling us anything about what your actual usecase is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
int i = 0;
int a = list.get(i++);
int b = list.get(i++);
int c = list.get(i++);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
Integer a = list.get(0);
Integer b = list.get(1);
Integer c = list.get(2);
```